# How can I fix Error: -69877: Couldn't open device after interrupted formatting process?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-format

This question, possibly the same question, has been asked: [Couldn't open device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224752/couldnt-open-device)

However, my question hopefully demonstrates a more specific scenario as the situation in which caused the error explicitly known:

The following done as a root user:

1. I plugged in my SD card and ran `diskutil list` to grab the internal device node (/dev/disk2)
2. I ran `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 GPT UFSD_EXTFS4 New 100%` (UFSD_EXTFS4 is ext4 provided by Paragon)
3. I saw that it was working, so I interrupted the process at step 2.
4. I attempted to rerun the command with the number of partitions explicitly stated `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 1 GPT UFSD_EXTFS4 New 100%`

I get the message:

```
Started partitioning on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

Running `gpt show -l /dev/disk2` yields

```
start     size  index  contents
    0  7741440
```

Running `gpt destroy /dev/disk2` yields

```
gpt destroy: unable to open device '/dev/disk2': Permission denied
```

It seems to me there is some lock on device disk2. I just need to figure out how to release it.

I was able to release it by rebooting into safe mode (holding shift key during boot) and then rebooting back into normal mode. I would like to know, however, what exactly could be done to release this lock without rebooting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run across something similar before and what I did was issue the command:

`diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskxx`

What you do when you shutdown and reboot, even in safe mode is you first unmount all your disks.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else who ends up on this question after searching online, be sure that you confirm that your SD card is not mounted as read-only! There is a physical tab that you may need to move:

[image]

Comment: +1 for nice illustration haha. It was not my problem, however. I ended up rendering my card useless by somehow corrupting some read-only bit (possibly alterable by `hdparm`, in my case not)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error message when trying to reformat my *encrypted* Seagate portable drive following the official website's [guide](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/how-to-format-your-drive-in-macos-1011-and-above-007736en/).

You can tell whether the hard drive is encrypted by 'Get Info' when right click on it in Disk Utility. I wasn't able to [decrypt](https://osxdaily.com/2016/10/25/decrypt-external-drive-mac/) it even though I have the correct password as the function was grayed out in Finder's right click menu for some reasons.

I solved it by erasing the *volume* first and then proceeded to erase the *drive* in Disk Utility. Obviously make a copy of everything you want to save before erasing.