# Can this SSD Hard Drive be used?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, ssd

I got a 2TB SSD to replace my Mac Mini's internal HD.
When trying to clone my HD, Carbon Copy Cloner encountered several errors, after which I wasn't able to erase the SSD HD with Disk Utility.

The drive started behaving [exactly as in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224752/couldnt-open-device).

I tried doing what the highest voted answer suggested in Terminal, [following these steps](https://silvae86.github.io/2020/10/15/restore-mac-dmg-only-using-terminal/).

As a result, I got a "Could not repartition target device" message from Terminal.

**Is there anything else I can do at this point?** (Please include Terminal command lines in your answers)

<sub>Mac mini (Mid 2011)</sub>

Comment: Which model of Mac Mini? What OS? Presumably this is a 2.5" SATA style drive? If the drive can't be erased, then I'd be tempted to ask for a refund/replacement.

Comment: Thanks. I added the model of the mac in the question. For some reason, I wasn't able to get a refund yet, which confirms my fears.